# Hudson - push the commit to production server

Tags: linux, svn, centos, hudson

We have first server with SVN, this SVN has configured hooks to be able to call second server (with Hudson) and do build of the app on the second server.

This is functionall and running fine... but when developing the app we need to test it before pushing it to all users (= we need third server with Hudson).

Of course there's no troubles with running the same architecture on the third server as on the first one.

Anyway we'd need "whatever", which would be able to simply push some commit on the devel server to the production server.

Is there anything, which would solve this problem? Some plugin to Hudson? Whatever...

Comment: As an FYI, I would post this question on Stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does deployment mean for that app (e.g. copying files, stopping and starting services, ...)?

Starting points:

- Plugins you can look up on https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins (for Jenkins) and http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins (for Hudson)
- If you have automated deployment script(s) but they only run locally, install a Hudson client (node/slave) on prod and configure a job that runs the script(s) to be run on the production machine only. Make sure that the artifacts are either accessible from the prod machine or that you push them over first.

Disclaimer: I am usually hesitant in using the same Hudson/Jenkins for dev and prod deployments. Be sure to set the permissions correct so not everybody can start the prod deployment.